# How do I use IFTTT with Instagram posts that use multiple photos?

Tags: if-this-then-that, instagram

IFTTT has many recipes that backup, repost, etc when you post an Instagram photo. However, these only appear to work with Instagram posts that use a SINGLE photo. Since Instagram provides functionality to include several (up to 10) photos on a single post, how do I backup/repost/etc these photos?